# What happens if we reuse "yii init" in same project folder

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I already have a yii2 advanced app in developement mode. I want to know what if I use **yii init** in same project folder with production mode? Will everything get erased or mode would be switched to production mode successfully?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I actually got an error when I tried. Got: `Error: Unknown command "init".`

Comment: What command did you use? I use "php init"

Comment: Just `yii init`. For migrations, similar works to me so I guessed it should be just `yii init`.

Comment: How to switch between modes? I am new to yii2 :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean "switch between modes"? You mean from development to production?

Comment: Sure @Edvin, my email id - ankursoni.leonardo@gmail.com. You can also tell me how to stop development mode and enter into production mode.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using app-advanced template, and my answer is for advanced template only.

The easiest and shortest way (but not secure one) is to define the configs in [enironment](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/tree/master/environments) dev and prod folders.

It contains config files that will replace your original `*-local.php` config files.

But be carefull with open-source repositories and don't store your passwords there ;)

---

And there is a great package for managing environments (which I personally use) by janisto - [yii2-environment](https://github.com/janisto/yii2-environment), read the docs for further info.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you will run
`./yii init` it will ask you questions (interactive mode). 
It will ask you in which env you want to run you app. Also it will ask if you want to overwrite files.
To run it in non-interactive mode run `./yii init --env=Production --overwrite=All`

---

To enable prod also delete/commentout these 2 lines in your `frontend/index.php` and `backend/index.php`

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i will try this and let you know.